# Return an array of functions?

Tags: javascript, wrapper

So I'm trying to write a helper library that will aid in the writing of tests, the tests run asynchronously but I need to force them to run sequentially. The way this is done by funcunit, the test framework we use at work, is to use nested callbacks, but these end up being 30 layers deep, hard to write, hard to maintain etc. etc.

I have some helper functions, makeTest and clickOn:

```
helpers.makeTest = function (f) {
    if(!helpers.tests)
        helpers.tests = //I want this to be an array of the functions returned by clickOn//;

    if(helpers.tests.length)
    {
        helpers.tests.shift()();    
    }
    else
    {
        ok(true, 'Tests passed');
    }
};



helpers.clickOn = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        selector = args.shift();

    return function() {
        var el = S(selector);
        el.exists(function(){
            S.wait(100, function(){
                el.click(function(){ 
                    helpers.makeTest();
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and i want to be able to write tests like:

```
test("copy folder with helpers", function () {
    helpers.makeTest(function(){
        helpers.clickOn("#openDialogFolder");
        helpers.clickOn("input#-2");
        helpers.clickOn("a#copyTrigger");
    });
});
```

However all that happens is the function passed to makeTest returns undefined, I want this to return an array of functions, any pointers?

EDIT: I seem to have solved my problem by, instead of having clickOn returning a function, creating a helper.queue = [] and pushing the function created by clickOn to that queue. Which I can access from makeTest

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes to doing this, one is prototyping your function, the other is to create the following which is the simplest for your purpose:

```
helpers = {
    clickOn: function () {},
    makeTest: function () {}
}
```

The prototype route would mean instantiating a new helper method to use its prototyped functions, which is great for keeping scope properly, but in your case is not really needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, I have a helper object with those functions already defined.

clickOn already, successfully creates a function that clicks the element, what I'm having trouble with is then accessing those functions in makeTest.

Comment: Sorry I think I may have got my wires crossed, can you set up a fiddle and I will have a look see if I can help

Comment: here's no need, ive solved my issue by creating a helper.queue and storing my functions there, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

To put your testsfunctions + arguments in an array you can do:

```
tests = [ // global variable
 [ helpers.clickOn, "#openDialogFolder" ],
 [ helpers.clickOn, "input#-2" ],
 [ helpers.clickOn, "a#copyTrigger" ],
 [ more_fkts, "other arg", 42 ]
]
```

and run tests

```
function runNextTest() {

 var test = tests.shift;
 if(test) {

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(test, 1);
      test[0].apply(null, args);
      runNextTest();
    }, 1);
   }
  }
```

however, to account for the way of asynchrony involved in your test-functions the call mechanism may have to be adapted. - The setTimeout is there only to 'simulate' the asynchronity of the test functions..

Comment: right, but the whole point is that i want to be able to write tests by just having a list of functions and executing them one after the other, this is a framework other people are going to be using and its extending an existing framework, so whats important is that modular tests can be written:

test("copy folder with helpers", function () {
    helpers.makeTest(function(){
        helpers.clickOn("#openDialogFolder");
        helpers.clickOn("input#-2");
        helpers.clickOn("a#copyTrigger");
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

The way that I solved this was to re-write the clickOn function so that instead of returning a functions, it pushed the function into a queue that makeTest executed one by one.